# What Does Factor Refer To In Matrix

Tags: matrices, factoring

Below is the excerpt from [this link](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/odds/zero.pdf) to prove the following proposition.

---

> **Proposition** $\ $Let $A$ be a square matrix over an arbitrary field with all row and column sums zero. Then all cofactors of $A$ are equal.

**Proof** $\ $ Let $A$ be $n × n$, and let $J$ be the all-1 matrix of size $n × n.$ We evaluate $\det(A + J)$ by performing row and column operations. We distinguish the first row and column for simplicity, but the same applies to any row and column. We do the following:

• Add all other rows of $A + J$ to the first. Then every entry in the first
row is n, while the other rows are unaffected.

• Add all other columns to the first. In the result, the $(1, 1)$ entry is $n$
2
;
all other entries of the first row and column are $n$; and the remaining
entries are unaffected.

**• Take out a factor n from the first row.**

• Subtract the first row from each of the other rows. The $(1, 1)$ entry of
the result is $n;$ the remaining entries of the first column are zero; and
the entries not in the first row or column are precisely those of $A,$ since
we subtract $1$ from each of them.

Thus, $\det(A + J) = n$
2A11, where A11 is the $(1, 1)$ cofactor of $A.$ As
remarked, the same applies to any cofactor; this shows that all cofactors are
equal.

---

I am trying to change this proof to prove more general case, where just row sum is zero.

I am following the above proof lines but can't understand the bold-faced step, which says "Take out a factor n".

How's **factor n** defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means that you should divide each element in the row in question by $n.$

Comment: factor = divide. see now.. thank you so much